# I need to dynamically addEventListener to objects in array

Tags: javascript, gsap

the event listeners were successfully added, if you replace menu[i] with menu[1] or menu[0] in the move_box function the buttons function. When I click on a button I get this error: **Uncaught Cannot tween a null target.**  I think it has something to do with the context of "this" in the function move_box.  I have this on JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/jimeast123/F4WkU/1/

```
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/latest/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
    .box {
      margin: 0px;
      height: 50px;
      width: 50px;
      background-color: blue;
        }
    li {list-style: none;}
    .inner {margin-left: -40px; display: block;}
    .inner li, .box {display: block;}

    #outer li { display: inline-block;}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<ul id="outer">
    <li><button type="button" class="toggle" name="btn1">Open</button>
        <ul class="inner">
            <li><div class="box"></div></li>
        </ul>
    </li><!-- end of outer li  -->
    <li><button type="button" class="toggle" name="btn2">Open</button>
        <ul class="inner">
                <li><div class="box"></div></li>
        </ul>
    </li>  <!-- end of outer li -->
</ul>  <!-- end of outer -->
<script>

var menu = document.getElementsByClassName('box');
var btn = document.getElementsByClassName('toggle');

 function move_box(e) {
   if(this.innerHTML === 'Open') { 
        TweenLite.to(menu[i], 2, {y: 100, ease:Power2.easeOut});
    this.innerHTML = 'Close';
    } else {
    TweenLite.to(menu[i], 2, {y: 0, ease:Power2.easeOut});  
    this.innerHTML = 'Open';    
      }
    }

for (var i = 0; i < btn.length; i++ ) {
    btn[i].addEventListener("click", move_box, false);
}


</script>   
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

The variable "i" is not defined at the time the function is called because it's part of the loop.  What you can do is use "this" to find the index of the button within the array, and then get the menu at the same index. The following code is untested but I think it will work:

```
TweenLite.to(menu[btn.indexOf(this)], 2, {y: 100, ease:Power2.easeOut});
```

If that isn't correct, I think it will at least point you in the right direction.

EDIT:

The following code works. It takes a different approach by navigating the DOM to find the related box.

```
var btn = document.getElementsByClassName('toggle');

function move_box(e) {
    if (this.innerHTML === 'Open') {
        TweenLite.to(this.parentNode.getElementsByClassName('box')[0], 2, { y: 100, ease: Power2.easeOut });
        this.innerHTML = 'Close';
    } else {
        TweenLite.to(this.parentNode.getElementsByClassName('box')[0], 2, { y: 0, ease: Power2.easeOut });
        this.innerHTML = 'Open';
    }
}

for (var i = 0; i < btn.length; i++) {
    btn[i].addEventListener("click", move_box, false);
}
```

Comment: now I have  TypeError: undefined is not a function but I think we're on the right track.

Comment: It seems like I would have to put the loop inside the event handler making it recursive.  I doubt that would work somehow.

Answer (score 0):

I found a fix I first set an Id on btn in the loop that btn + i then in the event handler I use getAttribute to retreve the id then use substr method to seperate out the number at the end if the id I then assign that number to a variable j and then use j as the array index for the menu array.  here's the script :

```
<script>
var i;
var menu = document.getElementsByClassName('box');
var btn = document.getElementsByClassName('toggle');

 function move_box(e) {
        var j;

        var id = this.getAttribute("id"); 
        j = id.substr(3,1); //get digit at end of id.
            if(this.innerHTML === 'Open') { 
            TweenLite.to(menu[j], 2, {y: 100, ease:Power2.easeOut});
        this.innerHTML = 'Close';
        } else {
        TweenLite.to(menu[j], 2, {y: 0, ease:Power2.easeOut});  
        this.innerHTML = 'Open';    
          }
    }

for ( i = 0; i < btn.length; i++ ) {
    btn[i].addEventListener("click", move_box, false);
    btn[i].setAttribute("id", "btn" + i);
}

</script>
```